# How to change the button into badge, if it is already approved?

Tags: laravel, datatables

how to change the button into badge if it is already approved? [from button to this badges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vx5xB.png)

```
->addColumn('action',
  '<a
     href="{{{ URL::to(\'subscriber/\' . $id . \'/edit\' ) }}}"
     class="btn btn-info btn-sm"
   >
      <span class="fa fa-edit"></span>
      Edit
   </a>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the value of approved status from the controller and use

```
<button class="badge badge-success{{$approvedStatus == 1 ? badge-success : 
badge-danger}} "> {{$approvedStatus == true ? Approoved: Deny}}</button>
```

Comment: it's giving me another error, is there any way to use like if else condition?

Comment: what is the error? And make your question more clear. Do you want your button to unclickable? or do you want you button type to change into badge? or just to change the text inside the button.

Comment: I had made your answer a bit easier. If it helps plz support and approve the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
->addColumn('action', '@if($is_approve == 0)
        <a href="{{{ URL::to(\'subscriber/\' . $id . \'/edit\' ) }}}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" ><span class="fa fa-edit"></span> Assign</a>
            @elseif($is_approve == 1)
                <span class="badge badge-success">Approved</span>

            @elseif($is_approve == 2)
                <span class="badge badge-danger">Deny</span>
            @endif
    ')
```

I'm sorry, but I got it now, thanks. [this is what I meant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQwn5.png)